# How do I connect ruby to mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I'm new in MacOs and in Ruby. I was playing a bit with Ruby on terminal, all went fine so far. Then I downloaded and installed the rails framework. All went fine! But when I start the server

```
rails server
```

and just after refreshing the "welcome aboard site" I get this error in terminal:

```
Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)):
mysql2 (0.3.11) lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
mysql2 (0.3.11) lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
```

There are more lines of errors, but I'm sure they are all related with couldn't find and/or couldn't connect to mySql. I have had installed the mySql server before installing rails to use it with Apache/PHP. So I think there must be somewhere a file to say rails where the server is or maybe tell rails user/password?

I was looking for a solution on Google but I just got results of people having troubles because of different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify mysql username and password in **config/database.yml** file

for eg, for development environment:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: < your database name>
  username: <your usename>
  password: <your password>
```

You can add more properties if you want, i've showed here only required fields.

Thanks

Comment: No, thanks to you! :) Sometimes I will see things more complicated as they are.

Comment: Yes of course it has. Now I need just create the tables and go on. Thank you again.

Comment: I just noticed that I should accept answers, don't knew that before and I think it made me seem a bit ungrateful. However, solved. :-P